# If $(κ_t)$ is a semigroup with invariant measure $\mu$ and $ν$ is singular to $\mu$, then $νκ_t$ might not converge to $\mu$ in total variation norm

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $E$ be a Polish space, $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ invariant with respect to $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $\nu$ be a probability measure $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ singular to $\mu$.

> I've read that if $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is *not* strongly Feller$^1$, then we cannot expact that the composition $\nu\kappa_t$ tends to $\mu$ in total variation distance. How do we see this?

And does "cannot expect" mean that there are instances of the setting such that the convergence does not hold or can we even show that it's impossible to hold in general?

---

$^1$ $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is called *strongly Feller* at time $t\ge0$ if $\kappa_t f$ is continuous for all bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: "We cannot expect" would ordinarily mean "it is not generally true that".  In other words, there exists at least one non-strongly Feller example in which $\nu \kappa_t$ does not converge to $\mu$ in total variation.  Probably there are many such examples, but that's not necessarily implied by the wording.  It is certainly not claiming that *every* non-strongly-Feller semigroup fails to converge.

Comment: In the general situation that you describe here, the wording that you quote seems a bit odd: In fact, even if the semigroup *is* strongly Feller we cannot expect convergence in total variation norm of $\nu \kappa_t$ in case that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular. And conversely, if the semigroup is not strongly Feller, we cannot expect convergence even if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are *not* singular. So in the situation you describe there are actually two different reasons why we cannot expect convergence, in general.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, I know that even for a strongly Feller semigroup it is not guaranteed that convergence takes place. And that's why (@Nate) why I questioned what precisely is meant by "cannot expect", since it sounded like $\nu$ being singular to $\mu$ would somehow rule out that this is possible. So, maybe I didn't get your comment correctly, but can we generally infer something from knowing that $\nu$ is singular (or not singular) to $\mu$ at all?

Comment: @NateEldredge Please take note of my comment.

Comment: Well, what is true is the following: If $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and the semigroup is strongly Feller, then we always have convergence of $\nu \kappa_t$ as $t \to \infty$ with respect to the total variation norm (but not necessarily to $\mu$, if we do not assume uniqueness of the invariant measure). If one of the assumptions (strongly Feller or absolute continuity of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$) fails, convergence can fail (but does not necessarily fail).

Comment: Maybe one additional comment about the case where the semigroup *is* strongly Feller. In a way, the question whether $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular is a bit besides the point (as I said: if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular, convergence *can* fail, but there are also many situations where convergence still holds). What is more important is the dual structure of the fixed spaces of the semigroup: for strong Feller semigroups, we have convergence of $\nu \kappa_t$ for each $\nu$ if and only if the fixed measures of the semigroup separate the fixed functions.

Comment: As a simple example, consider $E = [0,1]$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, and $\kappa_t f = e^{-t} f + (1-e^{-t}) \int f\,d\mu \cdot 1$, a process which jumps at rate 1 to a uniformly chosen point.  This is not strongly Feller but we have $\nu \kappa_t = e^{-t} \nu + (1-e^{-t}) \mu$ which does indeed converge to $\mu$ in total variation, even for $\nu$ which are singular to $\mu$.

Comment: @NateEldredge So, can you make any sense of the quote? (it's taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602479.pdf)(p. 4, second paragraph)

Comment: I don't think it's anything more than that their semigroup is not strong Feller, and therefore they cannot conclude *from standard theory alone* that $P_t^* \mu \to \mu$ in total variation in the singular case.  It may be possible to get that conclusion, or convergence in some other mode, under additional assumptions, and that's what the paper is about.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a condition that, in particular, guarantees that your semigroup has a **unique** invariant (stationary) measure, which is quite strong. There are lots of examples without this property. For a very simple (if somewhat degenerate) example notice that if you do not impose any continuity assumptions on the transition probabilities at all, then there is no way the behaviours of $\kappa_t\mu$ and $\kappa_t\nu$ can be related if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular. Take a partition of $E$ into two measurable sets $A$ and $B$, take $a\in A, b\in B$, and let $\kappa_t$ send any point from $A$ to $a$, and any point from $B$ to $b$. Then the semigroup $\kappa_t$ has two invariant measures $\delta_a,\delta_b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) I guess your intention is that $\mu(A)=\nu(B)=0$? (b) You wrote that "there is no way" when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are singular, but as long as I got you right you've only provided an example that there is a particular semigroup such that there is more than one invariant measure, which is a different claim.

Comment: (c) What I want to know is how this is particularly related to the convergence in total variation norm. The quoted claim in the question is taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602479.pdf) (p. 4, second paragraph) and it's indicated that convergence might hold with respect to a coarser topology (like an appropriate Waserstein distance).

Comment: @RW: I'm not sure whether I understand your reference to "continuity assumptions on the transition probabilities" correctly. It seems that continuity could only help to avoid the scenario that you describe if we assume in addition that $E$ is connected.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck Any Markov kernel can be considered as a map assigning to any point $x$ from the state space the corresponding transition probability measure $\pi_x$, and what I meant is the continuity of this map in an appropriate topology (for instance, the standard Feller condition is precisely the continuity of this map in the weak topology). It has nothing to do with the connectedness of the state space.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Look up the description of various Feller type properties for the Markov kernel determined by a family of transition probabilities $\pi_x$ in terms of the continuity of the map $x\mapsto\pi_x$ in the corresponding topologies. For instance, see Chapter IX Definition 8 of the book by Dellacherie - Meyer quoted in the article you mention.